# Why does the LLC converter have an Lm inductor? How does it interact with the LC circuit?

Tags: resonance, resonant-converter

**Task:** to understand why the LLC converter has Lm inductance and how it interacts with the LC circuit.

**What I learned:**

1. LLC converter circuit:

[image]

The LLC converter is a DC to DC buck converter (transformer n >= 1).
Cr, Lr, Lp(Lp) - form a resonant tank.

Since the resistance of the inductor increases with frequency and the resistance of the capacitor decreases, at the resonant frequency the resistance Cr, Lr is 0.

2. I introduced the LLC converter as an equivalent controlled voltage divider (X1 - Cr, Lr and X2 - Lm, Rload). That is, there will be a total voltage drop at the resonant frequency at X2.
3. I checked this circuit in the simulator.

[image]

When I input a square wave 230..0VDC at the output, I get a sinusoid +115..-115VDC (at the resonant frequency).

[image]

By removing the Lm inductance, the signal has changed slightly (seen at the very beginning). The output is also about + -115VDC.

[image]

I learned that Lm is a magnetizing inductance and most likely it provides a higher current stability at the output of the converter.

**Questions:**

1. What role does Lm provide?
2. The resistance of Cr, Lr at the resonant frequency is 0Hz. Will Lm interfere with this behavior? Otherwise Cr-Lr = 0Ω, Lm has resistance.
3. Is Lm a separate inductor or is it usually already in the transformer design?
4. Additional question (if you can answer it)

The LLC receives 230VDC input.
Transformation ratio n = 2.

This means that at the resonant frequency the output of the transformer will be Vin/2 = 230/2 = 115V.

Will it be effective if this divider factor is changed by increasing the frequency?
That is, I will lower part of the output at the divider, and the rest at the transformer.

Comment: The inductors in your diagram are labelled `Lr` and `Lp`. There is no `Lm`  ?

Comment: In the diagrams, it is designated as Lp and Lm. It is identical in placement.